# Source code for standard typeclass instance declarations

Tags: haskell, hackage

I was wondering about the `Ord` instance declaration for `(a,b)`, and I wanted to do a quick lookup on hackage to confirm my intuition that the comparison is first on `a` and then, in case of equality, on `b`. Specifically I went [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Ord.html#t:Ord). Since hackage has links to the source code for data declarations and functions, I assumed that there would also be source code for instance declarations, but I can't find them. Is there a reason why they are not there, or have I just not looked hard enough? `type Answer = Either Explanation Directions` :)

Comment: There is an open ticket to [add source links for instances](http://trac.haskell.org/haddock/ticket/145) in Haddock, which would make finding instances much easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot. All good answers, each with a little extra information that makes them stand out from the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went [looking in the Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t%3aOrd), clicked on the [source link for the `Ord` typeclass](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/src/GHC-Classes.html#Ord), scrolled down a little, and found that it's defined as

```
deriving instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (a, b)
```

It's using the [StandaloneDeriving](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/deriving.html#stand-alone-deriving) extension. Basically it's generating the same code as if the type was defined as

```
data (a, b) = (a, b) deriving Ord
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Ord` instance for tuples [is derived](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/src/GHC-Tuple.html#%28,%29), according to the rules from the language specification, which goes back [as far as Gofer](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gofer-prelude/2.30.3/doc/html/src/Prelude-Gofer.html#line-622).

```
instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (a,b) where
    (x,y) == (u,v)  =  x==u && y==v

instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (a,b) where
    (x,y) <= (u,v)  = x<u  ||  (x==u && y<=v)
```

Answer (score 4):

The Haskell 98 Report specifies this [in section 10.1](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/derived.html):

> The class methods automatically introduced by derived instances of Eq
>   and Ord are (==), (/=), compare, (<), (<=), (>), (>=), max, and min.
>   The latter seven operators are defined so as to compare their
>   arguments lexicographically with respect to the constructor set given,
>   with earlier constructors in the datatype declaration counting as
>   smaller than later ones.
>
> Derived comparisons always traverse constructors from left to right.
>
> ...
>
> All derived operations of class Eq and Ord are strict in both arguments.